# How to wrap all methods in Rails console (IRB) in a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html and can see various ways to customize IRB. But did not see how to:

Write a block (or method) such that whenever a command is run in Rails console it runs the block.

For example:

```
begin
  puts :before
  yield
  puts :after
end
```

Then, when you do

```
=> puts :OK
:before
:OK
:after
```

Comment: Have you got a chance to customize it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to switch from IRB to Pry (the `pry-rails` gem will load it automatically for `rails c`), it provides [a hooks API](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Hooks) that should do what you need. It sounds like you'd want the `:before_eval` and `:after_eval` events.

I don't know of an equivalent mechanism for IRB, though it should be possible to hack something using TracePoint.